# How many ways are there to choose 16 cookies?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to choose 16 cookies if there are six varieties of cookies including chocolate chip, and at least six chocolate chip cookies must be chosen?

Is $C(n+r-1,n-1)$ correct where $n=16$ and $r=6$?

(There is an unlimited amount of each typy of cookie)

Comment: Are you assuming unlimited quantity of each type of cookie?

Comment: @jdods Yes there is

Comment: Do you mean permutations (specific orderings) or combinations ?

Comment: @DavidQuinn Combinations

Comment: So now the question reduces to choosing $10$ cookies out of $6$ varieties, with no restrictions. Can you handle this ?

Comment: Is "choosing 6 chocolate chips first then 10 others" different from "choosing  10 others first then 6 chocolate chips"?

Comment: @mvw No it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Hint:$

First take out the $6$ chocolate chip cookies anyways. Now the problem reduces to choosing $10$ cookies from $6$ varieties with no restriction, which is the stars and bars problem, with $n=10$ and $r = 6$

Comment: So is $C(n+r-1,n-1)$ correct with $n=10$ and $r=6$. I made a mistake, I meant to ask it this way, but I do not want to change the question now.

Comment: The second parameter should be $r - 1$. Otherwise it sees OK. That was probably just an oversight.

Comment: I like to turn it around and think of it as throwing 10 balls into 6 buckets, and considering how many ways there is to do that. I find it easier to think of it this way. The 6 buckets represent the types of cookies, and we are choosing a total of 10. Personally, I can more easily make sense of this as a multiset/stars-&-bars problem.